# Import not finding sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I list my tables and I see the my target. Then I try .import and its replies "No such table."

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot commands must not be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks! But then what a terrible error message sqlite gives! "No such table," when the problem is "Don't use a semi-colon." (Obviously I am not blaming you for SQLite's error messages.)

Comment: @GeneCallahan How is it supposed to know that, it just expects a tablename

Comment: Well, it HAD a table name. And it could "know that" because there was the semicolon right at the end of the line.

Comment: Have you ever written a parser, Sami? I've written several. It's trivially easy to catch a mistake like that and give a proper error message.